# get pagename in my wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am adding specific js file to the front end from my wordpress plugin.

For Example :

```
if($wp->query_vars["pagename"] == 'pagename1'){
   include js file 1.
}else if($wp->query_vars["pagename"] == 'pagename1'){
   include js file 2.
}
```

But now i am not able to get the page name in$wp->query_vars.

Thank you
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$post = get_post();
$post_name = $post->post_name;
```

To add javascript you could do this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addSomescripts' );
function addSomeScripts() {
    $post = get_post( );
    $post_name = $post->post_name;
    if($post_name == 'pagename1') {
        wp_enqueue_script('script1', '/pathtoscript1.js');
    } else if($post_name == 'pagename2') {
        wp_enqueue_script('script2', '/pathtoscript2.js');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you invoking the code? ie is it in a certain action?

Comment: no not in action, basically i wont just add js alone .Behind that we have some logic too......

Comment: But what causes that code to run? There must be something calling it from Wordpress. eg. I updated above with how you might add scripts according to post name. I'm wondering where in the Wordpress system the code is being invoked, to return null.

Comment: as i said before i am not only adding javascript according to the page.If that particular page is running i will save data to the db.So there are lot of functionality behind that.

Comment: Sure, that's just an example of where you might call it to add javascript. But whatever it does, it has to live somewhere. Where is your code currently called from?